# Show page name after home url

Tags: urls

I have custom post type 'campaign' and in browser it is showing  like this

```
https://www.inbreakthrough.tv/campaigns/bellbajao/
```

but I want to show it after home url like this ..

```
https://www.inbreakthrough.tv/bellbajao
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) set `with_front` to `false` in the [rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite).

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'  => 'campaigns',
    'with_front'  => false,
)
```